# GET data from GitHub is Possible, GET data from dribbble doesn't work

Tags: jquery, json, github, dribbble-api

I've used this piece of code to GET data from the GitHub API

```
var name;
var description;    
var html_url;
var username    = "PirateStef";
var updated_at;
var language;       
var repo;
var urlGitHub       = 'https://api.github.com/users/'+username+'/repos?sort=created';

$.getJSON(urlGitHub, function(json){
    repositories = json;
    outputGitHubContent();      // GitHub Content         
}); 

function outputGitHubContent() {


    $.each(repositories, function(index){
        name            = "<div class='name'>" + repositories[index].name + "</div>";
        description     = "<div class='description'>" + repositories[index].description + "</div>";
        updated_at      = "<div class='updated_at'>" + repositories[index].updated_at.substring(0,10) + "</div>";
        html_url        = "<a class='html_url'  target='_blank' href='" + repositories[index].html_url + "'>";
        language        = "<div class='language'>" + repositories[index].language + "</div>";

        repo            = "<div class='repo'>" + html_url + "<div>" + name + language +  "</div>" + description + updated_at + "</a> </div>";

        console.log(repositories[index].owner.login);

        $("#github").append(repo);
    });
};
```

This is the Github API url

```
https://api.github.com/users/PirateStef/repos?sort=updated
```

I've tried to build a function to GET the dribbble data. Using the api.dribbble url below.

```
http://api.dribbble.com/players/PirateStef/shots/
```

I'm having trouble getting the "title" from each object.

---

The dribbble code that isn't working

```
var urlDribbble     = 'http://api.dribbble.com/players/'+username+'/shots/';
var shot;   

$.getJSON(urlDribbble, function(json){
    shots = json;
    outputDribbbleContent();    // Dribbble Content         
}); 

function outputDribbbleContent() {


    $.each(shots, function(index){
        console.log(shots[index].title);
    });
};
```

gets me 5x undefined

```
console.log(shots[index]);
```

gets me this

```
[
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
, 
Object
]
```

Comment: What is `dribble.com`? It looks like an unused landing page. Why would you expect an API call designed for one website to work on another?

Comment: It looks like I misread the domain; there's a third `b`: http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/. The question about why you'd expect an API call crafted for GitHub to work on Dribbble still applies.

Comment: @Chris Yes it's dribbble, it's a heb site where designers can post photo's of design work.

Comment: not all API's are available via ajax if they aren't either CORS or jsonp enabled...check API docs. Also some require authorization in request

Comment: @charlietfl does this mean that even though I can view the data in the api.dribbble page, I can't GET the data via ajax?

Comment: not absolutely, but possibly yes. Read the API docs

Comment: What does "I'm having trouble getting the "title" from each object" mean? Are you getting a response, but having trouble parsing it? If so, what does the response look like? Is the API request failing entirely? Do you see any error messages?

Comment: @Chris I get either `[object], [object], [object]` or `undivinedundivinedundivinedundivined`

Comment: @user3199999, so you're getting a response. Something is probably wrong with your code. Instead of showing the working GitHub code, please show us the Dribbble code that *isn't* working.

Comment: @user3199999, have you registered your application and authenticated before sending your request, as specified in the [API documentation](http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/)?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late to the answer but I recently working on some part of dribbble and come to know about these:

```
'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/users/'+user_id+'/buckets?access_token='+dribbble_access_token
```

This will provide user buckets data as:

> created_at
>   description
>   id
>   name
>   shots_count
>   updated_at

Now to get shots you can use:

```
'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/buckets/'+bucket_id+'/shots?access_token='+dribbble_access_token
```

or

```
'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/users/'+user_id+'/shots?access_token='+dribbble_access_token
```

This will provide 12(default) shots data with all possible resolution images.
Though I am still looking to any parameter to manage the limit, i.e, 12 by default.

Ok, I got the solution to set limit as well. The parameter that is to be passed is

> per_page

This can receive any numeric value. So my final url is:

```
'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/users/'+user_id+'/shots?per_page='+limit+'&access_token='+dribbble_access_token
```

> I have used it in a beautiful [Multi social tabs](http://joomla30.webkul.com/multi-social-tabs.html) module of Joomla
>   by [Webkul](http://webkul.com/), have a look at it by following the [link](http://joomla30.webkul.com/multi-social-tabs.html) then
>   simply check dribble tab there

Answer (score 0):

I've used the jribbble plug-in, this way I don't have to register an app with dribbble.